# Tensorflow 2.0: kernel_constraint not working

Tags: constraints, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I tried to impose some constraint to convolution layer, but it seems not working.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1),
                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(-20.),
                            kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.non_neg(), padding='valid')
x = np.reshape([1. for i in range(9)], (1, 3, 3, 1))
y = c2(x)
print(y)
```

I expect 0 as answer, but instead it gives me

`tf.Tensor([[[[-180.]]]], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)`

which ignores kernel_constraint function.

do I miss something or is it a bug? btw, I use Windows as platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It boils down to whether the initializer or the constraint takes precedence when a Layer object is first built. It appears that in this case, the initializer takes precedence. This makes sense, given what's said in the documentation of Keras constraints:

> "Functions from the constraints module allow setting constraints (eg.
>   non-negativity) on network parameters during optimization."

(Reference: https://keras.io/constraints/).

The keyword phrase is "during optimization". In the case of your code examples, there is no optimization (i.e., no training or `fit()`) calls involved. Your code can be modified slightly to show that the constraint is actually working:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1),
                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(-20.),
                            kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.non_neg(), padding='valid')

x = tf.constant(np.reshape([1. for i in range(9)], (1, 3, 3, 1)))

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(0.01)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  y = c2(x)
  print(y)
  gradients = tape.gradient(y, c2.variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, c2.variables))

print(c2.get_weights())  # <-- See that the weights are all 0s now.
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation